# Jquery slider on divs hide whole div when trying to slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make Jquery function that slide between 4 divs.

first it checks if the first div is the active one and hides the previous arrow and if the last div is the active one it hides the next arrow.

when i click on next it supposed to remove the active class from the current div and fade it out then add the active class to the next div and fade it in.

but what happens that it fade out the current div and nothing else appears.

https://jsfiddle.net/73tdyfuL/3/

this is my html code

```
    <div class="test">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="client active">
                    <img src="images/test.jpg">
                    <p>These guys are incredible! I get my project in 10 days and it was awesome! <br>
                    Very good service! Highly recommended!</p>
                    <h4>John Smith</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="client hidden">
                    <img src="images/test.jpg">
                    <p>These guys are incredible! I get my project in 10 days and it was awesome! <br>
                    Very good service! Highly recommended!</p>
                    <h4>Ahmed Ragab</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="client hidden">
                    <img src="images/test.jpg">
                    <p>These guys are incredible! I get my project in 10 days and it was awesome! <br>
                    Very good service! Highly recommended!</p>
                    <h4>Amr Diab</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="client hidden">
                    <img src="images/test.jpg">
                    <p>These guys are incredible! I get my project in 10 days and it was awesome! <br>
                    Very good service! Highly recommended!</p>
                    <h4>santa cluse</h4>
                </div>

                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x">P</i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x">N</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my css

```
.test{
    background-image: url("../images/testmonials.jpg");
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.test img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.test p{
    margin:40px auto;

}

.test h4{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.test i{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.test i:hover{
    color: #f76003;
}


.test .fa-chevron-left{
    left: 0;
}

.test .fa-chevron-right{
    right: 0;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

and the Jquery

```
$(function () {

    'use strict';

    //check testimonials
    var leftArrow = $('.test .fa-chevron-left'),
        rightArrow = $('.test .fa-chevron-right');

    function checkClients() {
        if ($('.client:first').hasClass('active')) {
            leftArrow.fadeOut();

        } else {
            leftArrow.fadeIn();
        }

        if ($('.client:last').hasClass('active')) {
            rightArrow.fadeOut();
        } else {
            rightArrow.fadeIn();
        }
    }

    checkClients();
    $('.test i').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('fa-chavron-right')) {
            $('.test .active').fadeOut(100, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active').next('.client').addClass('active').fadeIn();
                checkClients();
            });
        } else {
            $('.test .active').fadeOut(100, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active').prev('.client').addClass('active').fadeIn();
                checkClients();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code has a typo: `if ($(this).hasClass('fa-chavron-right'))` - it should be: `if ($(this).hasClass('fa-chevron-right'))`. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/y9sueshy/.

Comment: @andreivictor sorry but i can't notice the difference between both codes ?!
can you explain more ?!

Comment: The typo is in the class name: it should be `fa-chevron-right` (with *e*) , but you typed: `fa-chavron-right` (with *a*).